# Ruin probability with mixture of exponentials

Tags: exponential-distribution, mixture-distribution

I suppose that we have the classical ruin model $U(t) = u + ct -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{X_i}$, where $X_i$ is a mixture of three exponential random variables $$ f_X(x) = p_1 \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x} + p_2 \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x} + p_3 \lambda_3 e^{-\lambda_3 x},\;\; p_1 + p_2 +p_3 =1 $$
I know that the probability of ruin is $$\psi(u) = c_1  e^{-r_1 u} + c_2  e^{-r_2 u} + c_3  e^{-r_3 u} $$ where $r_i$ are the solutions of the adjustment coefficient equation $Μ_Χ(r) = 1+(1+\theta)rE(X)$.

I know that if I have two Exponential distributions, these equations are $$ c_1  + c_2 = \frac{1}{1+\theta} \\ c_1 r_1  + c_2 r_2 = \frac{\theta}{(1+\theta)^2 E(X)} $$
My question is how can I find the parameters $c_i$ in case of three Exponential distributions. Especially, I want to find the third equation.